# How to AutoSave Instagram Photos on my PC based on Hashtag

Tags: instagram, hashtag, autosave

Is there a way I can grab or auto download/save all #hashtag photos on Instagram? For example, If I have a code / program already, then someone with public profile upload a photo on instagram with #hashtag, it should automatically saved on my folder or drive, is it realistic / possible?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Instagram changed their API so you can only download photos YOU post with a specific hashtag through IFTTT. A huge bummer. As a digital marketer, I instructed our team post with a specific hashtag and I was able to automatically download these to a flickr account where I could repost from our organization's Instagram account and use for other marketing purposes. Probably not the most legal method, but our organization was small and everyone knew what the hashtag was being used for.

Answer (score -1):

IFTTT.com

1. Create account
2. Activate Instagram channel
3. activate Dropbox channel (or other depending on your destination preference)
4. Create below recipe

IF THIS [photo uplaoded with #hashtasg on Instagram],
THEN THAT [photo automatically downloads to dropbox]

Enjoy!